# How to save a datafile in python

Tags: python, database, save

They let me at school make a program at school to roll a die 100 times, save it to a file and then graph the results. I already made the program but I can't save it, I tried this but I can't see the file, could someone help me please?
This is my code:

```
import random
import pickle

def dado(n):
  result = []
  for i in range(0,n):
    result.append(random.randint(1, 6))
  return result
print(dado(100))

#save the list
pickle.dump(dado, open("dado.txt", "wb"))
```

Comment: `dado` isn't anything in your pickle line.  After your `print()` check, do say `my_info = dado(100)` then change `dado` to `my_info` in the pickle line.

Comment: I did but I can't read de file, is normal? @BruceWayne

Comment: I am not familiar with pickle but why not output to a text document without it?

Comment: Without using pickle? I don't know how to do it without using pickle, I was searching and found that the easiest way was to use pickle.@BruceWayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this save program may like this

```
import random
import pickle

def dado(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        result.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    return result
    print(dado(100))

#save the list
pickle.dump(dado(100), open("dado.pkl", "wb"))
```

or

```
import random
import numpy as np

def dado(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        result.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    return result
    print(dado(100))

#save the list
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
np.savetxt("dado.txt", dado(100), fmt='%.1f')
```